# How i can start n new activity when a Navigation item is clicked in Android java

Tags: java, android

I want to start a new activity when a user clicks on Nav Item named as a logout. I am not finding any suitable syntax or a proper way to do it

navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                int id=destination.getId();

```
            if(id==R.id.nav_tools){
                finish();


            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: when nav_tools item of navigation drawer is clicked i want to start a new activity that would be the login activity

Comment: Hi, Tejas, what have you tried to start an activity?

Answer (score 3):

**Try below code for open new activity from nav item click**

```
 if(id==R.id.nav_tools){
               if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
                Intent settingIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingIntent);
            }
```

Comment: if this worked for you then you can give vote and appreciation also